# EF Code First validating and updating objects

Tags: entity-framework, validation

I am working on an N-tier application consisting of a UI layer (MVC), a Business Layer, a Domain layer (for the models) and a DAL for repositories and the EF DbContext.

I'm a bit confused about the inner workings of Entity Framework when updating the properties of an existing object and I'm looking for a good way to validate an object before updating its values in the database.

I have the following model:

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public int BlogPostId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following methods in my manager in BL:

```
public BlogPost AddBlogPost(string title, string description, byte[] image = null)
{
    BlogPost blogPost = new BlogPost()
    {
        Title = title,
        Description = description,
        DateTime = DateTime.Now
    };

    Validate(blogPost);
    moduleRepository.CreateBlogPost(blogPost);

    return blogPost;
}

public BlogPost ChangeBlogPost(BlogPost blogPost)
{
    moduleRepository.UpdateBlogPost(blogPost);
    return blogPost;
}
```

And I have the following methods in my DAL:

```
public BlogPost CreateBlogPost(BlogPost b)
{
    b = context.BlogPosts.Add(b);
    context.SaveChanges();

    return b;
}

public BlogPost UpdateBlogPost(BlogPost b)
{
    context.Entry(b).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();

    return b;
}
```

**My question now is: what's a good way to check that the model is valid before actually trying to change its values in the database?**

I was thinking something like this:

```
public BlogPost ChangeBlogPost(BlogPost blogPost)
{
    // STEP 1: put the updated data in a new object
    BlogPost updatedBlogPost = new BlogPost()
    {
        Title = blogPost.Title,
        Description = blogPost.Description,
        Image = blogPost.Image,
        DateTime = blogPost.DateTime
    };

    // STEP 2: check if the model is valid
    this.Validate(updatedBlogPost);

    // STEP 3: read the existing blog post with that ID and change the properties
    BlogPost b = moduleRepository.ReadBlogPost(blogPost.BlogPostId);

    b.Title = blogPost.Title;
    b.Description = blogPost.Description;
    b.Image = blogPost.Image;
    b.DateTime = blogPost.DateTime;

    moduleRepository.UpdateBlogPost(blogPost);
    return blogPost;
}
```

EDIT: I figured it's maybe better to just accept primitive types as parameter in the above method instead of the object.

I have a feeling that's too much work for a simple update, but I couldn't find anything else on the internet.

It's probably also worth noting that I'm using a **singleton** for the DbContext so I have to make sure Entity Framework doesn't change the values in the database before checking that those values are valid (since another call to the context by another class can cause SaveChanges()).

I know singleton on a DbContext is bad practice, but I saw no other option to avoid countless exceptions when working with multiple repositories and entities being tracked by multiple context instances.

PS: I also read about change tracking in Entity Framework but I'm not 100% sure how this will affect what I'm trying to do.

All suggestions and explanations are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I kinda answered my own question while doing some research and testing with some dummy data. I thought that when a property changed in MVC as a result of an Edit view, EF also tracked it and changed it in the database.

I figured out that's not how model binding works and realized after some fooling around that model binding actually creates a new object (instead of editing the properties of a dynamic proxy).

I guess I can now just validate the model and then just update the one with the same primary key in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You would check ModelState.IsValid. There are a lot of validation mechanisms built into MVC that you can take advantage of. [Built in attributes](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation) such as [Required] that you reference above, [custom validators](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2), making your business class implement IValidatableObject, overriding EF SaveChanges() to name a few. This article is a good start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx

Comment: Thank you Steve for your answer! That gave me some more insight :)